# Webhook - Receive POST data

Tags: vb.net, webhooks

I have a file where in the Page_Load I need to receive a webhook with POST data.

The json file's structure that I receive is something like this:

```
{
    "IdTransaction": 9999999,
    "TransactionStatus": {
        "Id": 1,
        "Code": "1",
        "Name": "Paid"
    },
    "PaymentMethod": {
        "Id": 1,
        "Code": "1",
        "Name": "Credit Card"
    },
    "Application": "App",
    "Vendor": "Vendor",
    "Amount": 1,
    "IncluedDate": "2020-02-13T14:57:20.9",
    "InstallmentQuantity": 0,
    "SecretKey": "SECRET_KEY",
    "Reference": "Pedido 48"
}
```

And my code, trying to get the POST data, is:

```
Dim s As Stream = Context.Request.InputStream
s.Position = 0
Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(s)
Dim json As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
```

But so it does not work. My question is, how to identify that somebody is accesing that page and sending a POST file (json) and how to extract that file to string?

Is a server side code and a ASP.NET app. The post is send by another server, the application who proccess the payments and returns a webhook with status changes.

Comment: 1. Is your code server-side or client-side?  2) Is this a ASP.NET or MVC app?  3) What is sending the POST (a web page, some client app, another server)?

Comment: Is server side code and a ASP.NET app. The post is send by another server, the application who proccess the payments and returns a webhook with status changes.

Comment: Since it is plain-text (not a massive binary) you should be able to use `Request` to grab the content.  If it was sent with a field name, it is easier to get with `Request.Form("FieldName")`

Comment: And if it does not have a field name?

Comment: You might be able to get it with `Request(0)` or you could resort to `Request.BinaryRead`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525710(v=vs.90)

Comment: I tried all ways and no success... On converting the result to string, allways returned an empty string. When I tried with Dim vntPostedData = Request.BinaryRead(Request.TotalBytes), it returned a string with "System.Byte[]" content.

Comment: Try using PostMan to intercept the communication.  Look at the message being sent to your app, to confirm that it isn't broken, and also if there are any info that you can use to un-package or extract the info that you need. https://blog.postman.com/debug-api-requests-mobile-postman-proxy/  It just sounds like something might already be wrong, or unusual, etc. Try to isolate or eliminate that first.

Comment: Sending a POST from PostMan, with header Content-Type as multipart/form-data and sending a Multipart Form with a name (like 'test') and the json in the value, i am getting, in my vb.net code, the same json as result (with Request.Form("test").ToString). Great! But, without a parameter name, using just Request.Form(), i'm just getting trash, like "=%7b%0d%0a++++%22IdTransaction%22%3a+9999999%2c%0d%0a++++%22TransactionStatus%22%3a+%7b%0d%0a++++++++%22Id%22%3a+1%2c%0d%0a+++++". Is it needing a charset maybe?

Comment: That looks like "url encoded" (plus = space, %22 = ", etc). URLDecode might help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.urldecode

Comment: Perfect! Worked! Thank you very much for all the help and time @tgolisch!